# Basis of induced representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup. My lecture book (Algebra by Cohn) defines the (right) $G$-module induced by a right $H$-module $U$ by
$$\tag{1}
\text{ind}_H^GU=U\otimes_{kH} kG,
$$
where $kH$ and $kG$ are the group algebras of $H$ and $G$, respectively. Since the tensor product is balanced with respect to the elements of $kH$, the basis of $(1)$ must be given by
$$\tag{2}
B_1=\{\mathbf{u}_i\otimes_{kH}\mathbf{e}_g\mid \mathbf{u}_i\in B_U, \mathbf{e}_g\notin kH\setminus \{1\}\},
$$
where $B_U$ is a basis of $U$ and $\mathbf{e}_g$ a basis element of $kG$. However, Cohn writes that the basis can be written
$$\tag{3}
B_2=\{\mathbf{u}_i\otimes_{kH}\mathbf{e}_t\mid \mathbf{u}_i\in B_U, t\in T\}
$$
where $T$ is a transversal for $H$ in $G$. But this does not seem to add up, because $\dim{B_1}=\dim{U}(|G|-|H|+1)$, whereas $\dim{B_2}=\dim{U}|T|=\dim{U}|G|/|H|$, and these values are not necessarily the same, hence, either $B_1$ or $B_2$ is not a basis. I assume that the author is correct, so $B_1$ is not a basis, but why?

Comment: consider the case when $U$ is trivial and let $g \notin H$ and $h \in H$, so $hg \notin H$ too. Then $1\otimes g = 1 \otimes hg$, so the elements of $B_1$ are not linearly independent. (Actually this isn't quite true - you've written $B_1$ as a set - but you must mean a list because of the way you're counting the elements)

Comment: @MatthewTowers, I meant a set. I used the fact that for vector spaces $U$ and $V$, with bases $B_U$ and $B_V$, the basis of the tensor product $U\otimes V$ is $\{u\otimes v\mid u\in B_U, v\in B_V\}$. But I can see that this does not carry over when we consider tensor products over ring modules.

Comment: If you really do mean a set then you can't count its size that way because you don't know that the elements that look distinct actually are distinct (and they're not, in some cases...)

Comment: @MatthewTowers, that solves my doubt then. As I said, I constructed $B_1$ using my knowledge of bases of tensor products of vector spaces, in which case the elements $u\otimes v$ _are_ distinct when $u$ is from a basis of $U$ and $v$ from a basis of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

> so $B_1$ is not a basis, but why?

It is linearly dependent if $H$ is not trivial.

For instance, for any $g\in G\setminus H$, $h\in H$ and basis vector $u_i$ we have $u_i\otimes hg=u_ih\otimes g$, and $u_ih$ can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors. You avoided producing linear dependence when $g\in H$ by forcing only one member of $H$ to be used in the basis (the identity $1$), but this logic needs to be applied not just in $H$ itself but in *every* coset of $H$.